# Java - Wait for component to be shown

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, callback, components

**UPDATE #3:** After madProgrammer's suggestions, maybe the timed solution is the best. But no answer has been given to this strange behaviour.
I understand the fact that components are not shown immediately and need to be set.

**The problem here is the onShow method, which executes correctly if called from onCreate, but doesn't work if called from the callback method "componentShown".**

---

**UPDATE #2:** Added a componentListener on fragmentContentPane, to see when actually this component is shown and **VALID**

```
fragmentContentPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){

    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){

        if (e.getComponent().isValid()) System.out.println("SHOWN AND VALID!");
    }

});
```

---

**UPDATE:**
The show method now gets called in EDT.

```
public void show() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException{

    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Showing..");
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

By now, the problem still exists.

---

**Original Post:**

I have this code:

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TEST {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JScrollPane contentPane;
    private JPanel contentViewport;

    private JScrollPane fragmentContentPane;
    private JPanel fragmentContentViewport;

    public TEST() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException{

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){

                onCreate();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onCreate(){

        System.out.println("On create!");
        frame=new JFrame();
        contentPane=new JScrollPane();
        contentViewport=new JPanel();
        contentPane.setViewportView(contentViewport);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){

            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){

                onShow();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onShow(){

        System.out.println("On show!");
        fragmentContentViewport=new JPanel();
        fragmentContentPane=new JScrollPane(fragmentContentViewport);

        fragmentContentPane.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {

            public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {

                if (e.getChangeFlags()==HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED && fragmentContentPane.isShowing()) {

                    System.out.println("Component is completely shown");
                }
            }
        });

        contentViewport.add(fragmentContentPane);
    }

    public void show(){

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException{

        TEST t=new TEST();

        t.show();
    }
}
```

The task is simple. I want to get known when the fragmentContentPane has been correctly added and is completely shown.

With this code this never happens, why?

**Everything works if the onShow method is called in the ThreadEvent** together with onCreate, for example:

```
public TEST() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException{

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){

                onCreate();
                onShow();
            }
        });
    }
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: any method that affects the UI has to be called from the ui thread.

Comment: checked, everything, from onCreate method to onShow method gets called in EDT.

Comment: t.show() is not inside the UI thread. let me run the code here

Comment: updated, but stil same problem

Comment: It's not entirely possible to determine when a component is fully realised on the screen, there are a number of conditions which must be meet to fully achieve the result. The API attempts to provide a "reasonable estimation" based on the visible state of the parent component and if it's attached to a native peer or not, but this is no guarantee that the component is actually been rendered by the system on the the screen

Comment: Thanks for your help @MadProgrammer . Could you please suggest something better in order to achieve this? I need to do something when everything is ready (shown, and so with size values not zero)

Comment: On create!
Showing..
On show!
I get all the messages

Comment: I've used a `ComponentListener` in the past and monitored the `componentResized` event, using a `SwingTimer` to wait a specific period of time to allow the events to stabilise

Comment: @MadProgrammer, so this means that i have to "manually" wait for some time and then hope everything is ok?
Efekctive Thanks for the effort, but the important message here is "Component is completely shown". This won't appear.. never, and that's not what i want. i need that code to be run.

Comment: The event may not be firing because the hierarchy has not changed. When the listener is registered the components  have already been added and there are no further changes to the hierarchy

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi It's little difference to what you're doing now, EXCEPT, it takes into a account that when a component is added/shown on a container, it may no have a defined size yet, as the layout pass hasn't run.  It's also possible for a component to be resized a number of times, when ever a layout pass takes place, so what it's trying to do, is find a "reasonable" time in the component's life cycle when you can start make determinations about the state of the component

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will try the solution you have just proposed. could you suggest some numeric value which matches the "reasonable" amount of time?
Efecktive, hierarchy changes happen, if you try to print a message to scan for the hierarchyevent changeFlag, you will obtain two messages, displaying 6 and 1 as changeflags.

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi I sit around 250 millisecond delay and simply reset the timer each time `componentResized` is called, once the `Timer` is triggered, I disable the `ComponentListener`, but you'll need to play around with it

Comment: Please check my answer, the weird behavior gets weirder.